# Navigating to the earliest/latest command in history when you're in the middle of your history

Tags: bash, command-line, command

Say I am in a bash terminal and have a large history of commands. I pressed the up arrow a whole bunch of times and am in the "middle" of the history. I want to now navigate to the first or the last command in my history quickly (without holding down the up or the down arrow for a long time). Is this possible? If so, what is the shortcut key to achieving this?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Take a look in the [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Commands-For-Manipulating-The-History):

```
man bash
```

Here I copied for you the thing you were looking for:

```
previous-history (C-p)
    Fetch the previous command from the history list, moving back in the list.  
next-history (C-n)
    Fetch the next command from the history list, moving forward in the list.  
beginning-of-history (M-<)
    Move to the first line in the history.  
end-of-history (M->)
    Move to the end of the input history, i.e., the line currently being entered.
```

Comment: Note that when META key does not work, you can use Escape and then < or >.

Comment: How to do it in vi mode?

Comment: For those who still feel lost: C is Control and M is the Meta key. [More in this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/19565/323990). For some systems the Meta key is Alt or Alt + Shift.

Comment: Under Ubuntu 16.04 with an English keyboard I had to press Alt + < and Alt + Shift + < to jump to the beginning/end of the history.

Comment: @totymedli thank you so much :D I think for people who know what "M" means, they wouldn't be looking for the answer.

Comment: I'm using a Hungarian keyboard. ">" is AltGr+Y, so to jump to the end of history, I need to press Alt and AltGr+Y.

Answer (score 23):

Depending on how things are set up for your terminal, you can usually do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break you back to the beginning (no comment) and then go up once or twice to get to the recent command you want.

Alternatively, using the `history` command will list all the recent commands used with index values associated with them. `!#` where `#` is the index number will rerun that command. There's a nice usefulness of the command `history | grep [command]` to try and find a specific command in your history.

Comment: ctrl-r allows you to reverse-search your history.

Comment: I didn't know that `Ctrl`+`C` also got back to the end of the history. +1 because I'm using `byobu`, so`Alt`+`>` is mapped to different functionality.