# Keyboard shortcut to jump to the end of the command history in ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, history

I searched the web for this already, with no success. The question is: is there any keyboard shortcut to jump right to the end of the command line history?

I ask because I often use the reverse-i-search <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd> feature to quickly find a previous command in the history, but then I may change my mind and type the command from scratch without overwriting any previous command (so clearing the line with <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + K</kbd> is not an option). Thus I want to jump back to the empty command line (past the end of the command history).

Right now I can only achieve this by scrolling the history using the down arrow key until I hit the end of the history, but it can be painful since I sometimes have to pass through plenty of entries before reaching the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ctrl + C  and UP arrow key.
Ctrl + C -> exits the current browsing of history with Up/Down Key.
Up arrow key -> To get the latest command.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was only looking for a way to get to the empty line, after the latest command. So, just Ctrl + C will do.

Answer (score 3):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3992155/1494454) pointed out you can use <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd>.

Usually the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key is mapped to the <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys. The <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> keys varies a lot depending on the keyboard and the layout you use.

| Indicated shortcut | US-EN shortcut | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>, (comma)</kbd> | Beginning of history |
| <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> | <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>. (period)</kbd> | End of history |

[Check out this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19565/323990) to understand the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key.

Comment: I think this is the better answer, but as it was stated it was incorrect and unclear. Control-C, as used in the other answer, actually inputs a break (SIGI signal) towards the terminal and moves to the next line. Basically, removing the history is a side effect of that.